# Excel error 1004 'No cells were found '

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

So, this throws up error 1004, no cells were found, they way i have handled the errors dont seem to work. Is there anyway i can avoid that error? Thanks!

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()

On Error Resume Next
Dim rrange As Range
Dim VisibleRange As Range
Dim rcell As Object

Set rrange = Sheets("Project details").Range("A2:A150")

Dim byCSMCoprId As String 'corp id goes into criteria for autofilter.
byCSMCoprId = TextBox1.Text
On Error GoTo Error_Handler
With Sheets("Project details").Range("A1:M1")
    .autofilter field:=2, Criteria1:=byCSMCoprId
    .autofilter field:=7, Criteria1:=""
End With
Set VisibleRange = rrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each rcell In VisibleRange
        ComboBox1.AddItem rcell
Next
Error_Handler:
If Err.Number = 1004 And Err.Description = "No cells were found." Then GoTo Message:

Message:
    MsgBox "No cells were found"
End Sub
```

Comment: change `With Sheets("Project details").Range("A1:M1")` to `With Sheets("Project details").Range("A1:M150")` and see if that helps :)

Comment: Also, I think you just want to do `Then GoTo Message`, don't include the colon afterwards.

Comment: tried them! doesnt work. gets stuck at
    Set VisibleRange = rrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd find something like this easier to follow:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Enter()

    Dim rrange As Range
    Dim VisibleRange As Range
    Dim rcell As Object

    Set rrange = Sheets("Project details").Range("A2:A150")

    Dim byCSMCoprId As String 'corp id goes into criteria for autofilter.
    byCSMCoprId = TextBox1.Text

    With Sheets("Project details").Range("A1:M1")
        .autofilter field:=2, Criteria1:=byCSMCoprId
        .autofilter field:=7, Criteria1:=""
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set VisibleRange = rrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error Goto 0

    If Not VisibleRange Is Nothing Then
        For Each rcell In VisibleRange
            ComboBox1.AddItem rcell
        Next
    Else
        Msgbox "No cells found"
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, tried but no luck. still error 1004 on Set VisibleRange = rrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Comment: Check your VBA settings - do you have "Break on all errors" set?  If Yes you should switch to "break in class module" (?) instead.

Comment: Tim, sir, genius!  Thanks. I had manually changed the settings to break on all errors.